# Store both BBCode and HTML version in database?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, forum, bbcode

On Stackoverflow I've found questions about storing BBCode OR HTML into the database, but what about storing both? For example, I would create `posts` DB table with two columns: `body_bbcode` & `body_html`.

In `body_bbcode` I would store original post submitted by a user (forum member), and in `body_html` I would store parsed (HTML) version of that post.

So, for displaying forum posts I would use `body_html`, but for editing & quoting (replying with quote) I would use `body_bbcode`.

The reason why I want to do this is because the parser is using regex and without `body_html` it would need to convert at least *15* forum posts per topic page. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that can cause performance issues?

On the other hand, I didn't see anyone doing like this so I'm wondering what are the disadvantages of this approach, besides taking up more space in the Database?

Also, I am thinking of adding a new column in which I would store plain text version for search purposes, so that the tags themselves aren't searched (for example `body_text`).

Comment: Why would you need to store the actual HTML into the DB? The actual HTML would be static among all of the forum members. You just need to store the 'post' or 'text' and parse the BBC right?

Comment: @Tony It is explained but you obviously didn't read: `The reason why I want to do this is because the parser is using regex and without body_html it would need to convert at least 15 forum posts per topic page. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that can cause performance issues?`

Comment: *"Correct me if I'm wrong, but that can cause performance issues?"* - Can it?  Have you tested this and measured an actual problem?  Are those performance issues worth the added complexity of storing the same data in multiple places?  It seems to me that you'd want to prefer storing the raw backing data and performing calculations/substitutions on that data on the fly.  There certainly *are* cases where one would trade performance for complexity, but one should certainly *measure* the performance before doing so.

Comment: So this is a bad idea. I'll tell you why... We use software from a third party. The third party decided it was a ***"good idea"*** to store raw XML data into the database. Now our database is over 22GB in size, half of which (yes literally 11GB) is one table. You may see miniscule performance issues with regex running on 15 posts, but think about a couple years down the road when your database is stupidly big. **Don't do it**. Use the regex and optimize its performance.

Comment: *"Correct me if I'm wrong, but that can cause performance issues?"* : Yes and no, You have to take in account that your server can also use a cache system.

Comment: Also note that bbcode is particularly verbose if you compare it with markdown (it's also a way to study, smaller size and probably faster to convert). One more thing, take care to do a smart html conversion (reduce the html attributes and use classes and a css stylesheet).

Comment: “Premature optimization is the root of all evil”, Donald Knuth 1974 [§](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_(1974))

Answer (score 0):

> The reason why I want to do this is because the parser is using regex and without body_html it would need to convert at least 15 forum posts per topic page. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that can cause performance issues?

A well designed bbcode regex will not hinder performance in any meaningful way.

Do not create "duplicate" columns for bbcode text and html text.

A major problem you run into with your suggested approach is that you will inevitably change your html code. (E.g., add a class to html links, change iframe dimensions of youtube embeds, etc.) Then you're stuck trying to update the data in the html column which would be problematic.